# On Page Load event in vaadin

Tags: vaadin

I have page with table that populates data based on complex query(takes lot of time even though I use pagination). I use BeanItemcontainer to load data in to the table. Now coming to the problem, I wish to load the data in to the table in a async way(after the complete page gets loaded on the user screen. I wan to populate the data). Is there some thing like onPageLoad event or onPageRenderEvent or equivalent that I can use to achieve this?

Details -

Version - Vaadin -7.0
Component  - Table
Data Container - BeanItemContainer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a number of ways to solve this, but you have to decide how you want to approach the problem. Here's two that I know of:

1) Request from the client.
2) Push from the server.  (technically still a request from the client)

1 -- A) Request from a Javascript function programmed on the client-side. Attach the component to a layout by using a [Javascript Extension](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Integrating%20a%20JavaScript%20library%20as%20an%20extension) or a [Javascript component](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Integrating%20a%20JavaScript%20component) and make requests by calling a [server-side API function](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Exposing%20server%20side%20API%20to%20JavaScript). You can then update the table within that request and not worry about syncing issues.

1 -- B) Make your own GWT / Vaadin widget (same thing, basically) to do 1A.

2 -- A) Request from a Vaadin component programmed on the "server-side." Make a visible (or invisible) [progress indicator](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/components.progressindicator.html) that polls the server. Populate the table in a background thread and Vaadin will send the data you've currently gathered. The progress indicator can do this many times and the table will only send the difference to the client-side code (called the delta). Be careful updating client-facing components from background threads; you need to sync on changes to the component to avoid concurrent modification errors.

2 -- B) Add a refresher to the application and follow 2A above without needing a progress indicator.

Either solution involves you explicitly updating the table, either in a background thread (2A,B) or in the server method called from the client (1A,B). And both are technically client-request based. The Vaadin team are working on adding true 'push.'

Comment: Very Exhaustive answer, Thanks for your pointers! I will try to implement this as the way you suggested and get back if any issues!

Comment: Hi Christopher, Sorry for accepting your answer a bit late, we went with Refresher Addon, now in 7.1 we are using UI polling.

Answer (score 0):

The Vaadin way to solve this problem is to use a lazy loading Container. There are several lazy loading containers available for Vaadin: SQLContainer in core, [LazyQueryContainer](http://vaadin.com/addon/lazy-query-container) and [JPAContainer](http://vaadin.com/addon/vaadin-jpacontainer).

Comment: Hello Henri, my apologies for the late response. As Christopher mentioned- we went with Refresher Addon in 7.0 and in 7.1 we are using UI Polling. Of course a background thread will update the content lazily.

Comment: Dont use JPA Container... Its way too slow

Answer (score 0):

You can add a load event listener in JavaScript and wait for it to be fired. A simple approach is to define a Java method that receives a
`Runnable` as a parameter and runs it when the page is loaded.

```
void onLoad(Runnable runnable) {
    Page page = UI.getCurrent().getPage();
    
    page.executeJs("window.addEventListener('load', () => {} );")
                .then( (event) -> runnable.run() );
   }
```

You can use it like this: `onLoad( () -> Notification.show("Page loaded") );`

Tested with Vaadin 24.3.2